# Does threads remove themselves from memory after finished running?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I have an application which creates 300-400 threads. Every thread has a different job to be done, nobody knows when they are going to end. So I've joined them to make my application wait for every thread to end. But when i run the software and track how many threads are running, even thread numbers are declining, my applications size in memory still gets bigger. So i wonder if threads clean-up after themselves in Ruby 1.9.2, and if they are not, what can i do about this?

Comment: What happens if you invoke `GC.collect` after joining each thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Ruby (MRI) doesn't release memory back to the system once it allocates some.

It can re-use it, but the memory isn't freed until process terminates.

Comment: i don't think it is reusing it because app size in memory continues to grow even when a thread terminates

Comment: Well, then you might have a leak there.

Comment: A leak in Ruby? That can't be it, unless there is an extension being used.